# Округлить углы при фокусе на input

Tags: html, css, focus

У меня есть `css` для `input` но при фокусе видно заостренные углы синего цвета. Как их сделать по краям поля ввода?

```css
#UsersPassword {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 6px 0 4px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  background: #F6F6f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="UsersPassword">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, почитайте, когда правильно применять [внутристрочное форматирование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/213987) и вообще, старайтесь не разукрашивать избыточным болдом текст - в глазах рябит от этого. Относится к последним вашим правкам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/310007 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/310013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синяя обводка при фокусе задаётся свойством `outline`. К сожалению, на него не действует `border-radius`, поэтому нужно просто менять цвет границы, а `outline` отключать.

```css
#users-password {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 6px 0 4px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  background: #F6F6f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#users-password:focus{
  outline:none;
  border-color:#2196F3;
}
```

```html
<input id="users-password" />
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: Там опечатка в слове "действует"